# Calling Selector to DismissViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, selector, swift2

How do I use selector to call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);`

```
    //MARK - closeBarButtonItem
    closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem();
    closeBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "closeIcon");
    closeBarButtonItem.target = self;
```

I have tried the below selector but it keep crashing saying no selector found

```
    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = "dismissViewControllerAnimated::";

    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = "dismissViewControllerAnimated:true:";

    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = "dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:";

    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = Selector("dismissViewControllerAnimated::");

    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = Selector("dismissViewControllerAnimated:true:)";

    //NO SELECTOR FOUND CRASH
    closeBarButtonItem.action = Selector("dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)";
```

Comment: Set the action like this:-
closeBarButtonItem
    closeBarButtonItem.action = "done"


func done {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid. I am wondering if it is possible to call the selector directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
closeBarButtonItem.action = "close:"

func close(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no directly way to do that, because if you use `@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)`, it will be called with the `sender` instead of the animated BOOL and the `event` instead of the `completion handler` block. These are not valid arguments.

If you want to shorten your code, you should use `JTTargetActionBlock` library, which will allow you add event handler to control directly. This is an Objective-C library, so use can use it through `Voice-Bridging-Header`

Example (not tested yet):

```
closeBarButtonItem.addEventHandler({(sender, event) in
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}, forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```